# Fixed header over gradient body (Mobile web page)

Tags: css

I want to know how can I have a fixed header over a body that has a gradient background (with scrollable content). I don't want to set a background-color for the header because it messes the page look cause I want the body's background to be shown in full size.

I'm using a gradient background on the body tag, something like this:

```
body {
background:radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(89,72,97,1) 0%, rgba(57,46,63,1) 100%);
}
```

And I have a sticky header:

```
.header {
    line-height: 45px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

And also scrollable content:

```
.content-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.content-wrapper .content-wrapper-inner {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

I know I can set `padding-top` for `.content-wrapper` but it doesn't behave nicely in iOS when viewed in different orientations and such.
Also I want to avoid `position:fixed` because it also doesn't function properly in iOS's Safari. when you try to scroll the whole page, the body's background gets dragged but the header stays in place with a blank background color.

Sorry for no Jsfiddle/Codepen Because I couldn't manage to set the radial gradient background.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Screenshots of current situation and desired outcome would be helpful.

Comment: Here is a basic jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6Lk8v14e/ - now what?

Comment: @Aziz Oh thx for the jsfiddle. Well the header has a `background-color`. I don't want it to have a bg-color

Comment: @Aziz I want it to be transparent, yet still hide contents behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to have the content below header, while header is `fixed` then you can try one of the following solutions:

**1. Offset content**

Add a `margin-top` to content equal to height of header (45px):

```
.content-wrapper {
    ⋮
    margin-top: 45px;
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/xj8qg5mj/

* This also works with padding, position-top etc

---

**2. Make header inherit body background**

```
.header {
    ⋮
    background: inherit;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/ga7ndq8c/

The `fixed` background-attachment ensures the gradient does not stop at the height of header but instead behaves as if set on body, see difference:

[image: fixed css gradient bg attachment difference]

Update: since you need support for Chrome on Android, you can use an alternative approach instead: pseudo element (`::before`) of header gets the background and has a height equal to 100% of viewport (`100vh`)

```
.header {
  ⋮
  background: inherit;
}

.header::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  background: inherit;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/ejg6sdmw/

---

**3. Get rid of the fixed position**

You could probably achieve the same result if you keep the header with static position and have the content-wrapper fill the remaining viewport space while its content is scrolled:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  height: 100%; color: #FFF;
}

body {
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(89, 72, 97, 1) 0%, rgba(57, 46, 63, 1) 100%);
  text-align: center;
}

.header { line-height: 45px; }

.content-wrapper { height: calc(100% - 45px); }

.content-wrapper .content-wrapper-inner { height: 100%; overflow: auto; }

.long {
  border: 1px dashed #CCC;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  min-height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">header</div>

<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="content-wrapper-inner">
    <div class="long">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium nemo repudiandae alias iure minima officiis eligendi minus dignissimos. Dolore eos, assumenda voluptatibus quidem sequi architecto suscipit. Doloremque, illo modi totam.</p>
      <p>Laborum reprehenderit deserunt tempora et minima animi atque libero aliquam, nesciunt perferendis omnis ipsam nostrum impedit quia neque adipisci amet quis corporis assumenda! Eveniet fugit quo pariatur officia et totam.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This seems to be the most simple and straightforward solution.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/uwuL51zg/

Comment: The `inherit` solution is exactly what I was looking for! I don't understand the `background-attachment` property though, a little explanation would help. thx

Comment: Well I just found the `background-attachment` is not supported on Android/Chrome browser :( And If I use Offset content I get unwanted behavior on iOS

Comment: Can you elaborate on the *unwanted behaviour*?

Comment: There 2 issues, First one is as I mentioned in the first post, when you're already at the top and try to scroll beyond, the whole body with its background gets dragged downside but the header stays in place obviously because of the `fixed` positioning and because the body got dragged, there is no body behind the header so you get to see a header with white background. The second issue is that when you change the orientation to Landscape, the padding effect goes away and you see the content overlap with the header.

Comment: I see. check my revision.